# django Get foreign-key model in view and show in html

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

So I have two models:

```
class UserMeasurements(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    set = models.ForeignKey(PhotoSets, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_measurements'

class PhotoSets(models.Model):
    image_dir = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, models.DO_NOTHING)
    set_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    photo_taken_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'photo_sets'
```

In the view.py I have :

```
def Main(request):
    measurement_list = UserMeasurements.objects.order_by('-time')
    photo_set_list = PhotoSets.objects.all()
    a = measurement_list.set.get_field('PhotoSets').rel.to
    //this is where I try to get the related models
    print str(a)
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'measurement_list': measurement_list})
```

I am trying to show the image_dir in the webpage with every User Measurement.
I checked other stackoverflow questions. But still I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do with that `a` variable, but you don't need to do any of this. You should just follow the foreign key when you output each measurement, eg in your template:

```
{% for measurement in measurement_list %}
  User: {{ measurement.user }}
  Time: {{ measurement.time }}
  Image dir: {{ measurement.set.image_dir }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this is explained quite fully in the docs, especially in the tutorial where they use the example of poll questions and choices.

Comment: Can you explain the .rel.to function a little bit? When's the time to use it. (a link is fine too)thanks

Comment: You shouldn't really ever use it; it's how Django keeps track of relations internally. If you're building a new database backend, or a new type of model interface, you might want to use it, but not otherwise.

Comment: Have a new question about django..(Could you please check my question list if you have time? thanks so much!)

Answer (score 2):

Would you give it a try in your main.html

```
{% for item in measurement_list %}

   {{ item.image_dir }}  

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks! Sorry that i can give you a vote up since I have only ten points :(